# Laravel 5 - API Resources with nested relations

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

First of all I've started to learn Laravel few weeks ago so sorry if I'm not using the right words while I'll explain my problem.

I'm trying to write some API to retrieve all posts in my DB and inside post's info I'd like to retrieve user's info related to every post (like username, id etc.)

**User Model:**

```
public function post()
    { return $this->hasMany(Post::class); }
```

**Post Model:**

```
public function user()
    { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }
```

then in my PostResource I try to return the post's data from DB

**Post Resource:**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'user_info' => HERE_I_WANT_USER[USERNAME,ID ETC.]
        'body' => $this->name
    ];
}
```

and in my PostController I've this function that return my collection:

```
 public function show() { 
      return PostResource::collection ( Post::get() );
 }
```

So every post is linked to every author thanks to "user_id" value.

Here is my question: What are the steps to achieve this?

I've already red Laravel Doc "https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships" making and UserResource and doing the same steps that I did before, but I'm not able to retrieve any data because my user's info return empty.

I'd like to understand better what are the steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would just call it like it is part of the Post model. Something similar to this:

```
return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'user_info' => $this->user
        'body' => $this->name
    ];
```

I'm assuming that `$this` is a Post Model. If its not, then you'll want to find it and use it instead like `$post->user`. Additionally, the name of the method will be whatever your relationship function is called (with out the parenthesis), so if that ever changes, you'll have to update this. Finally, this will return a User Model, so you can interact with it like a normal model (`$post->user->username` or whatever).

[Here is the Laravel Relationship documentaion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) for further reference.

Comment: I have never used the resource feature, but from the documentation I'd say that you could also use additional resource classes for relationships as showed in the documentation for conditional relationships. This way you could define a transformer for the `User` model in a central place (e.g. `UserResource`), which would ensure the result looks always the same on different resources (if this is desired...).